# Cannot package/build Electron Forge app for production

Tags: reactjs, electron, electron-forge

I'm using the current version(s) of Electron Forge, React, etc. via the EF React template. When I run the executable created with `package` or `make` (currently testing under Windows, but same behavior occurred under OS X) I get the unhandled error "React is running in production mode", which halts the application (AFAICT).

I've tried setting `NODE_ENV=production` before packaging or making but it hasn't made a difference. This is stock EF.

DevDeps:

```
"electron-forge": "^5.2.4",
"electron-prebuilt-compile": "4.0.0",
```

Deps:

```
"electron-compile": "^6.4.4",
"electron-debug": "^2.1.0",
"electron-devtools-installer": "^2.1.0",
"electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0",
"react": "^16.4.1",
```

.compilerc

```
{
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "application/javascript": {
        "presets": [
          ["env", { "targets": { "electron": "1.6.0" } }],
          "react"
        ],

        "plugins": [
          "transform-decorators-legacy",
          "transform-class-properties",
          "transform-async-to-generator",
          "transform-es2015-classes",
          "transform-object-rest-spread",
          "react-hot-loader/babel",
          "babel-plugin-root-import"
        ],

        "sourceMaps": "inline"
      }
    },

    "production": {
      "application/javascript": {
        "presets": [
          ["env", { "targets": { "electron": "1.6.0" } }],
          "react"
        ],

        "plugins": [
          "transform-decorators-legacy",
          "transform-class-properties",
          "transform-async-to-generator",
          "transform-es2015-classes",
          "transform-object-rest-spread",
          "babel-plugin-root-import"
        ],

        "sourceMaps": "none"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I can provide whatever other info is needed--this issue has bled me.